# SQL Server 2016 - Hidden Column Doesn't Return from Nested Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal

I hope someone can help me here. I'm not a SQL developer so my knowledge is quite limited.
I'm trying to return the ValidFrom column in a nested SQL query from scala, but it doesn't appear. I can return it from a non-nested query, but it needs to be nested. In its simplest format it looks like this:

```
select * from (select *, ValidFrom from [dbo].[Sale]) s
```

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain a few things, 1) Are you using a stored procedure to put your tsql code in and then calling that stored procedure by name via Scala? 2) why it needs to be nested? 3) is ValidFrom a column in the dbo.Sale table?

Comment: `*` returns all columns in the table, `*, ValidFrom` will return all columns AND a second instance of the `ValidFrom` column.  The nested query aspect of your example doesn't achieve anything, it just returns all columns from the inner query.

Comment: Hi, ValidFrom is a hidden column in the table and select * on its own doesn't return it. Yes it comes from a stored procedure, in scala your specific sql code is delivered in a nested format. I have a function in scala that determines the exact select needed for each table and then creates that bit of sql for me. this is then placed inside the nested part. ie: Scala generates SELECT * FROM ( my code )

Comment: Interesting, are you on SQL Server 2016 then?

Comment: yes, accessing the db through management suite. I'm not too familiar with sql

Comment: If I can get this to work n the sql management suite I can easily transfer into scala

Comment: Have you... tried it there?

Comment: Can you try listing the columns in the nested select?  Just try with one column and `ValidFrom` and see if it works.  `SELECT * FROM (SELECT col1, ValidFrom FROM Sales) s`

Comment: I've already tried that and still get the same results, it only brings back the column I spectified and not the ValidFrom

Comment: I'm trying all these in the management suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hidden status for the columns in the subquery will propagate to the outer query. Can you modify the outer query? Is so you can try something like:

```
SELECT *, ValidFrom FROM (SELECT *, ValidFrom FROM [dbo].[Sale]) s
```

If not, you can apply some transformation to the ValidFrom column in the inner query and the new column will not have a hidden status, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, CAST(ValidFrom AS DATETIME2(0)) AS ValidFrom FROM [dbo].[Sale]) s
```

Try to CAST it to the same datatype you are already using for the column. It will introduce at least an extra Compute Scalar operator in your plan, so try it and validate the performance.

Comment: The second suggestion works in the sql management suite, just trying it in scala now. Thank you